# Upgrade Magento 2.3.5-p1 to Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade, magento2.4

I'm trying to upgrade Magento 2.3.4 and Magento 2.3.5-p1 to the latest release of Magento 2.4,
Is that possible ?
And How can I do this with composer ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Unless you are in the Beta Program you will need to wait until general availability on 28th July 2020.

Comment: I know the 2.4 release availability , but there will be 2.3.5-p2 and 2.3.6 etc. i'm asking if it is possible to upgrade directly from 2.3.5-p1 to magento 2.4 ?

Comment: Yes, just follow the instructions that Magento provide on the website with regards to the things you need to do before the upgrade and the composer require / change the composer.json file as you usually would.

Comment: Please check here https://techurbane.com/how-to-migrate-magento-2-3-to-2-4/

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade Magento version 2.3.4 to 2.4.0 follow the below steps:

Magento 2 Version Upgrade Commands.

1. php bin/magento maintenance:enable
2. composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 --no-update
3. composer update
4. rm -rf var/*, rm -rf pub/static/* ,rm -rf generated/*
5. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
6. php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
7. php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:di:compile
8. php -dmemory_limit=4G bin/magento indexer:reindex
9. php bin/magento cache:clean
10. php bin/magento cache:flush

After upgrade, check your Magento version with the following command:

11. php bin/magento --version
12. php bin/magento maintenance:disable

Done.

If you have a problem with friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer try commmand line:

composer remove friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer

composer require friendsofphp/php-cs-fixer