# How to upgrade Magento clud 2.3.3-p1 to Magento cloud 2.4.4?

Tags: upgrade, magento-cloud, magento2.4.4, composer-update

I have followed https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/325148/67054

But on composer update step get many errors regarding fastly, cloud-metapackage and framework related.

Do I have to switch phpversion before updating or after updating?

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: What errors are throwing composer?

Comment: @RaulSanchez  Validating configuration files

E: Error parsing configuration files:
    - services.elasticsearch.type: "elasticsearch:7.16" is not a valid service type.
    - applications: Uncaught exception: The "json" extension is not supported for php:8.1
        at <script>:98:0
          throw("The \"" + unsupported_extensions[0] + "\" extension is not supported for " + service.type);

Comment: So, are you running php8.1?

Comment: Yes, I have added version in magento.app.yaml file php:8.1

Comment: I thought you were trying locally. Why not opening a ticket to Adobe support?